# Issue with getJSON from couchDB SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: json, couchdb

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>
> {"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[

Here's my script

```
function getJSONData() {
var value = [];
var couchDB ="http://X.X.X.X:5984/databasename/_design/name/_view/All%20Content?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON( couchDB , function( data )  {
        format: "jsonp"
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.rows, function(index, row){
        value.push(row.value);
         });
    });
}
```

How can I get well formed json back from this get request ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your server is returning [json](/questions/tagged/json) data and client is trying to read JSONP fromatted data. you should enable [jsonp](/questions/tagged/jsonp) on [couchdb](/questions/tagged/couchdb) by changing variable allow_jsonp to true under configuration tab.